# How do I calculate scores for skills?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

[image]

*(click for larger image)*

They might also be called proficiencies. Are they just the modifier of the appropriate skill or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Each skill says which attribute is used in the parentheses on the right side. For example the Skill *Deception* uses *Cha*. *Cha* means *Charisma*. This means that you just use your Charisma modifier. If you are proficient with a skill you also add your proficiency modifier, which is +2 at level 1. Your character has a Charisma modifier of +2 and a proficiency bonus of +2. So you just write +4 at *Deception*. You do this for all skills and add this bonus or malus to every roll where your DM says you are using this specific skill.

Str = Strength

Dex = Dexterity

Con = Constitution

Int = Intelligence

Wis = Wisdom

Cha = Charisma